# Keyboard shortcut and right-click-menu item to ZIP all selected files/folders (with or without password)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, zip

I'd like to be able to ZIP all selected files/folders in one keyboard shortcut. **How to enable this feature in Windows 7?**

Currently these are the options:

- *Right-click > 7-Zip > Add to temp.zip*
- *Right-click > Add to Temp.rar*
- *Right-click > Send to > Compressed (zipped) folder

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to have something like:

- <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> : zip selected files and automatically enter in renaming mode for the filename `temp.zip` (ready to be renamed)
- <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>: zip selected files with 7-zip and open the "Add to archive" dialog so that I can fill **in a password**.

What I've tried: Autohotkey with

```
#+z::
SendInput {AppsKey}7{Enter}
Return
```

I could do the same for `#z` with UP arrow, UP arrow, etc. but this is not very robust (sometimes the UI items change, etc.). Is there a better solution?

Comment: try using separate send commands for each keypress and put `sleep 200` between them, it should be robust then

Comment: @MikhailV Yes but for some specific file types, some other options might be displayed in the menus (it's the case IIRC), so using a UP UP etc. is probably not ok for all file types. Is there a technique to do this without using simulated keypresses, but rather calling commands directly?

Comment: without using context menu you mean? Yes I think, you can copy file paths to clipboard with `alt+h` then `c` then `p`. Then pass them to actual application (7-zip in your case). I would just use some more advanced file manager though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass ; explorer

    #z::
    explorer_path := "" ; empty this variable
    selection := ""
    filename := ""
    InputBox, filename, Enter a name for the archive, ,,300
    if ErrorLevel
        return
    explorer_path := GetActiveExplorerPath()
    selection := Explorer_GetSelection()
    ToolTip, Wait for `n%explorer_path%\%filename%.zip"
    Loop, parse, selection, `n
    RunWait, %comspec% /c "7z.exe a "%explorer_path%\%filename%.zip" "%A_LoopField%"",,hide UseErrorLevel    ; if it doesn't work replace 7z.exe with its path.
    Process, WaitClose, 7z.exe
    ToolTip
    return

#IfWinActive

; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=69925
GetActiveExplorerPath()
{
    explorerHwnd := WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
    if (explorerHwnd)
    {
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        {
            if (window.hwnd==explorerHwnd)
            {
                return window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
            }
        }
    }
}

; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=60403&p=255273#p255256
Explorer_GetSelection(){
   WinGetClass, winClass, % "ahk_id" . hWnd := WinExist("A")    ; %
   if !(winClass ~="Progman|WorkerW|(Cabinet|Explore)WClass")
      Return      
   shellWindows := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
   if (winClass ~= "Progman|WorkerW")
      shellFolderView := shellWindows.FindWindowSW(0, 0, SWC_DESKTOP := 8, 0, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH := 1).Document
   else {
      for window in shellWindows
       try  if (hWnd = window.HWND) && (shellFolderView := window.Document)
            break
   }
   for item in shellFolderView.SelectedItems
      result .= (result = "" ? "" : "`n") . item.Path
   if !result
      result := shellFolderView.Folder.Self.Path
   Return result
}
```